# ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular

Tags: angularjs, bower

These are my dependencies in the file `bower.json`. Most of them are related to AngularJS.

```
"dependencies": {
  "angular": "~1.3.0",
  "jquery": "~2.1.1",
  "requirejs": "~2.1.15",
  "angular-resource": "~1.3.0",
  "requirejs-domready": "~2.0.1",
  "requirejs-plugins": "~1.0.3",
  "bootstrap-sass-official": "~3.3.0",
  "requirejs-text": "~2.0.12",
  "bourbon": "~4.0.2",
  "jQuery-Tag-This": "~1.1.0",
  "angular-masonry": "~0.9.1",
  "intl-tel-input": "~3.7.1",
  "ngInfiniteScroll": "~1.2.0",
  "moment-jalaali": "~0.3.3",
  "owl.carousel": "*",
  "persian-datepicker": "~0.3.6",
  "persian-date": "~0.1.8",
  "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.14",
  "angular-cookies": "~1.3.15"
}
```

When I run `bower install`, it gives me this output with the error `ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular`:

```
bower doc-ready#1.0.x                   validate 1.0.4 against git://github.com/desandro/doc-ready.git#1.0.x
bower get-style-property#~1.0.4           cached git://github.com/desandro/get-style-property.git#1.0.4
bower get-style-property#~1.0.4         validate 1.0.4 against git://github.com/desandro/get-style-property.git#~1.0.4
bower matches-selector#~1.0.2             cached git://github.com/desandro/matches-selector.git#1.0.3
bower matches-selector#~1.0.2           validate 1.0.3 against git://github.com/desandro/matches-selector.git#~1.0.2
bower fizzy-ui-utils#~1.0.1               cached git://github.com/metafizzy/fizzy-ui-utils.git#1.0.1
bower fizzy-ui-utils#~1.0.1             validate 1.0.1 against git://github.com/metafizzy/fizzy-ui-utils.git#~1.0.1
bower get-style-property#1.x              cached git://github.com/desandro/get-style-property.git#1.0.4
bower get-style-property#1.x            validate 1.0.4 against git://github.com/desandro/get-style-property.git#1.x
bower angular#~1.3.0                      cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.20
bower angular#~1.3.0                    validate 1.3.20 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.3.0
bower angular#^1.3.0                      cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.0
bower angular#^1.3.0                    validate 1.5.0 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#^1.3.0
bower angular#>= 1.0.8                    cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.0
bower angular#>= 1.0.8                  validate 1.5.0 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>= 1.0.8
bower angular#>=1.2.0                     cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.0
bower angular#>=1.2.0                   validate 1.5.0 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1.2.0
bower                                  ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular
```

Could you tell me why it gives me this `ECONFLICT` error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45861497/2393789

Answer (score 7):

There is a conflict on your AngularJS version. Many of your dependencies have a dependency on AngularJS, and they are not resolved with the same AngularJS version.

You should try adding this in your file `bower.json`:

```
"resolutions": {
  "angular": "1.3.0"
}
```

Replace `1.3.0` by the AngularJS version you actually want to use in your project.

More information can be found on the [bower.json specification](https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/json.md#resolutions).

Comment: Could you provide more details? You still have the same issue?

Comment: yes , give same error

==>


bower angular                         resolution Unsuitable resolution declared for angular: 1.3.0
//////////
bower                                  ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular
//////////////
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12

Comment: Then it means your other dependencies require an angular version greater than `1.3.0`. You could try with a resolution to `1.5.0` but you will have to upgrade your main angular dependency from `1.3.0` to `1.5.0`. Could you try that?