# bower ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for jquery error even after adding resolutions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower, bower-install

```
"dependencies": { 
  "jquery": "~2.1.4", 
  "angular": "~1.5.0",
  ....
  ....
},
"resolutions": {
  "jquery": "~2.1.4",
  "angular": "~1.5.0"
}
```

**bower install angular-peity --save**

bower angular-peity#*           cached https://github.com/projectweekend/angular-peity.git#0.0.5
bower angular-peity#*         validate 0.0.5 against https://github.com/projectweekend/angular-peity.git#*
bower peity#*                   cached https://github.com/benpickles/peity.git#3.2.1
bower peity#*                 validate 3.2.1 against https://github.com/benpickles/peity.git#*
bower jquery#~2.0.3             cached https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.0.3
bower jquery#~2.0.3           validate 2.0.3 against https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#~2.0.3
bower jquery#>=1.6              cached https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#3.1.1
bower jquery#>=1.6            validate 3.1.1 against https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#>=1.6
bower jquery#>=1.7              cached https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#3.1.1
bower jquery#>=1.7            validate 3.1.1 against https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#>=1.7
bower jquery#1.9.1 - 3          cached https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#3.1.1
bower jquery#1.9.1 - 3        validate 3.1.1 against https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#1.9.1 - 3
bower jquery#>=1.4.4            cached https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#3.1.1
bower jquery#>=1.4.4          validate 3.1.1 against https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#>=1.4.4
bower jquery#^2.0.3             cached https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.2.4
bower jquery#^2.0.3           validate 2.2.4 against https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#^2.0.3
bower                        ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to start with is to do

```
bower cache clean
```

After that when you do

`bower install` it will ask you

```
Unable to find a suitable version for jquery, please choose one:
1) jquery#exampleversion1 which resolved to 1.5.3 and is required by demo1
2) jquery#^exampleversion2 which resolved to 1.5.3 and is required by app2    
3) jquery#>.examplegversion3 which resolved to 1.5.3 and is required by app3Test
```

then you can enter `!1` or `!2` , or whatever suits your needs the best.

Prefixing number with `!` essentially adds the resolution block into bower.json but it will give you more control over what's happening and it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error on Windows 10 with Git Bash for Windows

> ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for jquery

and it was not going to the part where I could choose options `!1` or `!2`

For me switching to Windows PowerShell solved the problem and runing the same command `bower install`

I am suspecting it was connected with the user permissions.