# Implement Angular Materials on Angular Seed Template fails

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular-seed

still learning angular and started to use the seed angular application skeleton.

There I got Problems to implement the angular-material library and CSS by npm/bower.

Thats my Problem:

```
$ bower install angular-material
bower angular-material#*        cached https://github.com/angular/bower-material.git#1.1.4
bower angular-material#*      validate 1.1.4 against https://github.com/angular/bower-material.git#*
bower angular-animate#^1.4.8    cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.6.4
bower angular-animate#^1.4.8  validate 1.6.4 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#^1.4.8
bower angular-aria#^1.4.8       cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-aria.git#1.6.4
bower angular-aria#^1.4.8     validate 1.6.4 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-aria.git#^1.4.8
bower angular-messages#^1.4.8   cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-messages.git#1.6.4
bower angular-messages#^1.4.8 validate 1.6.4 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-messages.git#^1.4.8
bower angular#1.6.4             cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.6.4
bower angular#1.6.4           validate 1.6.4 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.6.4
bower angular#1.5.11            cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.11
bower angular#1.5.11          validate 1.5.11 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.11
bower                        ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular
```

How can I solve this´?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45861497/2393789